# Equivalent to Pandas boolean indexing for xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, python-xarray, boolean-indexing

I have an xarray dataset that I would like to index using boolean indexing as I would with Pandas. For example, I have a pandas dataframe:

```
A B C
5 1 0 
4 1 0
3 5 0
4 3 0
5 2 0
```

And I want only rows where the value in B is greater than 2, like this:

```
df = df[df['B'] > 2]
```

would give

```
A B C
3 5 0
4 3 0
```

How could I do the same operation in xarray for an xarray dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#masking-with-where

i think you are looking for this

```
da.where(df.B > 2,drop=True) #da as a DataArray object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking to subset the data along axes based on a Boolean condition on one of the coordinates, you can do this with `.sel`:

```py
ds.sel(x=(ds.x > 5))
```

You can similarly select along one or more axes after a reduction operation returns Boolean data indexed by coordinates on the array:

```py
ds.sel(x=(ds.v > 5).any(dim="y"))
```

To subset the data using a multidimensional mask, use `.where`. Note however that xarray cannot drop arbitrary points from the middle of an array, you may end up with masked values (nans) still appearing in the result.